# Nodejs librería multer renombrar imagen tal que asi : "usuario._id+'img_perfil'"

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, fileupload, multer

Expongo lo que pretendo hacer:

Por ahora solo estoy con el `backend` es decir, con `NodeJS` , mis **dos cuestiones** principales son:

1. Estoy intentando modificar el nombre del fichero que quiero subir con la librería `multer`.

Mi `routes\user.js` es el siguiente:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const path = require('path');

const usuario_controller = require('../controllers/user');

//subida Ficheros
var multer  = require('multer');

const multer_storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:path.join(__dirname,'../imagenes'),
    filename:(req,file,cb)=>{
        cb(null,file.originalname);
    }
});

const upload = multer({
    dest:path.join(__dirname,'src/imagenes'),
    storage:multer_storage 
}).single('img_perfil');

router.post('/add',usuario_controller.añadir);
router.get('/all',usuario_controller.obtener_todos);
router.delete('/:id',usuario_controller.borrar);

router.post('/uploadImage/:id',upload,(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.file);
    var id = req.params.id;
    var nombre_img = id+'_imgPerfil';
    req.file.originalname = nombre_img;
    console.log('NOMBRE IMAGEN => '+nombre_img)
    res.send('Imagen subida');
})

router.get('/:id',usuario_controller.obtener_por_id);
```

En este **fragmento** :

```
const multer_storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:path.join(__dirname,'../imagenes'),
    filename:(req,file,cb)=>{
        cb(null,file.originalname);
    }
});
```

Configuro los ficheros que subo para que tenga el nombre del fichero y no nombres tales como : `876876sad768ad6876876ads876asd768` , una vez configurado se guardan con su **nombre** y **extension** correctos.

Pero lo que yo pretendo es lo siguiente:

Quiero que el usuario que se **registre** y suba su **foto de perfil** guarde dicha foto con el siguiente **patron** : `usuario._id` **+** `_imgPerfil` para que quede **almacenado la imagen** con un nombre parecido a : `5cae69fc61429c3674737ffe_imgPerfil` y asi tener un orden de las fotos y poder acceder a ellas cuando quiera.

2. A mi parecer lo veo un poco **desordenado** como tengo organizado la **libreria** `multer` , es decir, la tengo en el fichero **usuario.route.ts** que anque si es verdad que esta relacionado, no esta modularizado. ¿Sería posible tenerlo en una clase que **exporte** la **funcion** o algo así?

   ¿Como lo haríais vosotros?
   Es mas que nada por modularizar y abstraer n código de otro.

Me gustaría tener algo como sale en mi `route` de `Usuario`, asi : `usuario_controller.añadir` pero en este caso `usuario_controller.añadirFoto`

Finalmente dejo mis ficheros:

**/model/user.js**

```
module.exports = function () {
    var db = require('../libs/db-connection')();
    var Schema = require('mongoose').Schema;

    var User = new Schema({
        nombre_real:String,
        apellidos:String,
        pais:String,
        ciudad:String,
        email:{type:String,unique:true},
        nombre_usuario:{type:String, unique:true},
        password:String
    });

    return db.model('usuarios',User);
}
```

**/controller/user.js** :

```
const User = require('../models/user')();

exports.añadir = function(req,res){
    const {nombre_real, apellidos, email, nombre_usuario, password} = req.body;

    var newUsuario = {
        nombre_real,
        apellidos,
        email,
        nombre_usuario,
        password
    };

    User.create(newUsuario)
    .then(usuario=>{
        console.log("USUARIO PARA GUARDAR = "+usuario)

        if (usuario) {
            res.send({
                status:200,
                message:'Usuario añadido correctamente'
            })
        }
        if (!usuario) {
            res.send({
                status:400,
                message:'No se pudo crear el usuario'
            })
        }
    })
    .catch(err=>{
       if (err["code"] == 11000) {
            res.send({
                status:400,
                message:'Usuario o Email ya han sido registrados',
            })
        }
        else{
            res.send({
                status:400,
                message:'Error al guardar el usuario'
            });
        }
    });
}

exports.obtener_por_id = function(req,res){
    var id = req.params.id;
    User.findOne({_id:id})
    .then(usuario=>{
        if (usuario) {
            res.send({
                status:200,
                message:'Usuario encontrado',
                usuario:usuario
            });
        }

        if (!usuario) {
            res.sed({
                status:404,
                message:'Usuario NO encontrado'
            })
        }
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        res.send({
            status:400,
            message:'Error al buscar el usuario por ID',
            error:err
        })
    })
}

exports.obtener_todos = function(req,res){
    User.find()
    .then(personajes=>{
        if (personajes) {
            res.send({
                status:200,
                personajes:personajes
            })
        }

        else{
            res.send({
                status:400,
                message:'No se pudieron obtener los usuarios'
            })
        }
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        res.send({
            status:400,
            message:'Error al obtener a los usuarios',
            error:err
        })
    })
}

exports.borrar = function(req,res){
    var id = req.params.id;

    console.log('ID = '+id)

    User.deleteOne({_id:id})
    .then(usuario=>{
        if (usuario) {
            res.send({
                status:200,
                message:'El usuario se ha borrado correctamente'
            })
        }
        else{
            res.send({
                status:400,
                message:'No se ha podido borrar el usuario'
            })
        }
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        res.send({
            status:400,
            message:'Error al borrar el usuario',
            error:err
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Hola, te pregunto lo siguiente, aunque no tiene que ver con tu duda. ¿Porqué la extensión de tus archivos ***usuario.route*** y ***user.model*** son de tipo ***ts***?

Comment: realmente uno esta en un directorio `routes` y el otro en un directorio `model` y simplemente se llaman `user.js` pero pense que llamandoles `nombre+loqueEs` seria mas entendible.Es de forma aclarativa, mis ficheros se llama ambos `user.js` pero seria un lio referirse a ellos aqui asi. Un saludo @MauricioContreras

Comment: Las extensiones son ts porque son typescript. Se tenia que decir y se dijo.

Comment: Discupadme, teniais toda la razon, pero me habia despistado utilizando **nomenclatura de angular** , ya esta corregido. Muchas gracias

Comment: @abrahamhs, entiendo perfectamente que las extensiones ***ts*** son usadas por lo general con ***typescript***, pero sucede que el O.P. erróneamente las colocó así, ya que su código es JavaScript, y por eso le hice la pregunta, para saber si era error de tipeo o es que las usaba realmente así. Gracias por la aclaratoria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He venido siguiendo tu progreso con el desarrollo que realizas en Node, Express y Mongoose, y te aliento a que continúes.

En cuanto a tu pregunta, voy a tratar de responderla de acuerdo a lo que has presentado en tu código. En mi opinión yo cambiaría algunas cosas, sin embargo, es sólo mi opinión.

**Multer**

La librería [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) es un [middleware](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middleware) escrito para Node, y por lo tanto podemos usarlo perfectamente con Express.

Veo que en tu código tienes un endpoint así: `/uploads/:id`, por lo tanto y sin entrar en mucho detalle voy a darte una posible solución usando dicho endpoint.

En la documentación de `multer`, se indica que el método `diskStorage` acepta un JSON con las opciones que deseamos configurar.

Las opciones que se configuran son: `filename` y `destination`, la primera representa el nombre que deseas darle a tu archivo y la segunda representa la ubicación.

Ambos campos aceptan funciones, y es en dichas funciones que pondremos la lógica referente a la asignación del nombre de archivo y ubicación del mismo.

1. `filename`: Este campo acepta una función con los siguiente parámetros: `req, file, cb`, donde `req` es nuestro objeto `request` de Express, `file` representa la información del archivo que viene en nuestro `request` y `cb` es una función callback que se encargará de devolver el `string` con el nombre del archivo.
2. `destination`: Este campo también acepta una función con la misma estructura anterior.

La documentación de `multer` nos advierte lo siguiente: (traducción propia)

> Usted es responsable de crear el directorio cuando el valor pasado a `destination` sea una función. Cuando el valor se pasa como `string` *(en vez de función)* `multer` se encargará de crear el directorio por usted.
>
> Multer no añadirá ninguna extensión de archivo por usted, su función debe devolver un nombre de archivo completo incluyendo la extensión.

Debemos entonces procurar conocer el tipo de archivo que ha subido el usuario, y esa información la obtenemos del objeto `file`.

Necesitamos 2 cosas: el nombre completo del archivo para conocer la extensión y el `mime type` del archivo en caso que la extensión no estuviese presente en el nombre original del archivo. El valor del nombre lo obtenemos con `file.originalname` y el valor de `mime type` con `file.mimetype`.

Para construir la extensión podemos usar lo siguiente:

```
const path = require('path');
const mime = require('mime');
let ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
ext = ext.length > 1 ? ext : '.' + mime.getExtension(file.mimetype);
```

En el código anterior hemos construido la extensión del archivo a partir de la información del objeto `file`. Si el archivo original fue subido sin extensión (ext.length <= 1), entonces la extensión la asignamos de acuerdo al `mime type`.

Para usar `mime` debemos instalar la librería desde `npm`:

```
npm install --save mime@latest
```

Ahora ya podemos construir un nombre de archivo completo usando toda la información disponible.

Podríamos tener algo parecido a lo siguiente:

**routes\user.js** (ES5)

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const path = require('path');
const mime = require('mime');

// Creamos las opciones
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: path.join(__dirname,'../imagenes'), // <= si no existe, multer la creará
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        let ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
        ext = ext.length > 1 ? ext : '.' + mime.extension(file.mimetype);
        const fileName = req.params.id + '_imgPerfil' + ext;
        console.log('filename: ', fileName); // <= vemos el resultado
        cb(null, fileName);
    });

const upload = multer({storage: storage}); // <= aqui asignamos las opciones

router.post('/uploadImage/:id', upload, (req, res)=>{ // <= pasamos el middleware que subirá la imagen
    res.send('Imagen subida');
});
```

Con esto ya deberías poder subir las imágenes a tu servidor usando `multer`.

**Modularidad**

En cuanto lo de la modularidad, la verdad es que todo lo puedes modularizar, puedes crear un módulo en un archivo llamado `upload.js` y colocas lo inherente a `multer` en dicho archivo.

Por ejemplo:

**upload.js** (ES5)

```
const multer = require('multer');
const path  = require('path');
const mime = require('mime');

// Creamos las opciones
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: path.join(__dirname,'../imagenes'), // <= si no existe, multer la creará
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        let ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
        ext = ext.length > 1 ? ext : '.' + mime.extension(file.mimetype);
        const fileName = req.params.id + '_imgPerfil' + ext;
        console.log('filename: ', fileName); // <= vemos el resultado
        cb(null, fileName);
    });

const upload = multer({storage: storage}); // <= aqui asignamos las opciones

module.exports = upload; // <= exportamos el módulo
```

Luego en tu controlador solo realizas la importación:

```
const upload = require('path/to/upload');
```

De esta forma lo puedes reusar en otros controladores.

Recuerda que debes usar `enctype="multipart/form-data"` en tu `form` para que puedas usar `multer` en el servidor.

Puedes leer más de [`path.extname`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_extname_path) y de [`mime`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime) en sus sitios oficiales.

Espero que esto resuelva tu duda.

Comment: Muchas gracias como siempre Mauricio , me has ido ayudando en cada duda que encontraba, esa ayuda sin nada a cambio se valora muchisimo.  Dicho esto, me gustaria preguntarte si el leer y comprender correctamente de aqui https://www.npmjs.com/ se entrena ? jeje porque yo me puse a leer  la documentacion y no me aclaraba mucho, no por el ingles si no porque no sabia donde iba cada cosa. Un gran saludo. Estoy en deuda contigo. Muchas gracias por todo. Y gracias por animarme a que siga, eso hare .

Comment: Básicamente la información que consigas sobre las diferentes librerías o paquetes serán como manuales de uso de dichas librerías. Para nada pretenden ser un tutorial, solo una guía muy básica de uso. Creo que lo que más nos cuesta a los programadores es la documentación. Puedes conseguir algunos buenos post o tutos en la web, pero realmente la experiencia se obtiene por ensayo y error, y por supuesto aclarando dudas aqui en [es.so]. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

no recuerdo si se puede. Pero creo recordar que si uno usa JWT, en el multer tenía uno acceso a la info que venia en el token cuando ya pasa la parte de autorizacion.

```
const storage = Multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'uploads/profile_pictures/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        let user = req.decoded;
        cb(null, `${user.id}__imgPerfil.png`)
    }
});
```

segun yo si se podia :P combinando middlewares, saludos