# NodeJS express librerÍa multer asignar a mi modelo usuario.url_img el nombre de la imagen subida

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, multer

Haciendo referencia a mi **pregunta anterior** : [Nodejs librería multer renombrar imagen tal que asi : "usuario._id+'img_perfil'"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/253780/nodejs-librer%c3%ada-multer-renombrar-imagen-tal-que-asi-usuario-idimg-perfil/253847?noredirect=1#comment471569_253847)

Pretendo asignar el nombre con el que guardo mi fichero, que sigue el siguiente patron : `usuario._id`**+**`_imgPerfil`, a mi campo `url_img_perfil:String` de mi `Schema Usuario` . Mi **funcion** que hace la subida es la siguiente :

```
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const mime = require('mime');

//Creamos las opciones

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:path.join(__dirname,'../imagenes'),
    filename: function(req,file,cb){
        let ext  = path.extname(file.originalname);
        ext = ext.length > 1 ? ext: '.'+ mime.extension(file.mimetype);
        const fileName = req.params.id + '_imgPerfil'+ext;


        console.log('filename : ',fileName);

        cb(null,fileName);

    }
})

const upload = multer({storage:storage}).single('img_perfil')
module.exports = upload;
```

La cual conseguí gracias a mi **pregunta anterior**.
Como yo lo veo es de la siguiente manera:

En la **función** que me guarda la imagen haría un **getById** al usuario para obtener el campo `url_imagen` , luego asignarle la variable `fileName` y finalmente **actualizar** el usuario.

**Otra duda** que me crea los **middlewares** es que, en este caso :

```
router.post('/uploadImage/:id',upload,(req,res)=>{

    res.send('imagen Subida')
 })
```

Que es donde doy uso de mi función **upload** como **middleware**, **¿Yo no puedo acceder en ese Routing a las propiedades del middleware 'upload'?**

He intentado hacer esto :

```
router.post('/uploadImage/:id',upload,(req,res)=>{
    console.log('Nombre Fichero = '+upload.fileName);
    res.send('imagen Subida')
 })
```

el cual me devuelve `undefined`.

Esto es lo que estoy intentado actualmente, creo que estoy cerca:

```
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const mime = require('mime');
//uso db
const db = require('../libs/db-connection')();



//Creamos las opciones

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:path.join(__dirname,'../imagenes'),
    filename: function(req,file,cb){
        let ext  = path.extname(file.originalname);
        ext = ext.length > 1 ? ext: '.'+ mime.extension(file.mimetype);
        const fileName = req.params.id + '_imgPerfil'+ext;

        //PROBANDO...

        db.collection('usuarios').findOne({_id:req.params.id})
        .then(usuario=>{
            if (usuario) {
                db.collection('usuarios').update(
                    {_id:req.params.id},
                    {$set: {'url_img_perfil':fileName}}
                    ).then(usuario_actualizado=>{
                        cb(null,fileName);
                    })
            }
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            cb(err,null);
        })

        //..FIN PROBANDO

        console.log('filename : ',fileName);


    }
})

const upload = multer({storage:storage}).single('img_perfil')
module.exports = upload;
```

Comment: Puedes ver la edición a mi respuesta, creo que te quedará un poco más claro todo. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu solución funciona, pero rompe totalmente con los principios [S.O.L.I.D.](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID).

Básicamente le estás asignando a tu función que genera el nombre del archivo una funcionalidad que va más allá de su alcance.

La solución al problema, es usar los objetos a los que tienes acceso y que luego seguirán su camino hacia el siguiente `middleware`.

En este caso me refiero al objeto `request (req)` que pasamos al callback de nuestra función que genera el nombre del archivo.

La idea es enviar el nombre del archivo adosado a dicho objeto, de esta forma no alteramos para nada el propósito de nuestra función que genera el nombre del archivo.

Una forma de hacer esto podría ser la siguiente:

**upload.js** (ES5)

```
const path = require('path');
const mime = require('mime');
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:path.join(__dirname,'../imagenes'),
    filename: function(req,file,cb){
        const id = req.params.id;
        let ext  = path.extname(file.originalname);
        ext = ext.length > 1 ? ext: '.'+ mime.extension(file.mimetype);
        const fileName = id + '_imgPerfil' + ext;

        req.file_name = fileName; // <= aqui estamos seteando un campo en nuestro objeto request
        // Nótese que he escogido un nombre cualquiera para el campo, en este caso 'file_name'
        // Para usarlo debemos acceder usando este mismo nombre, como se verá mas adelante

        cb(null,fileName);
});

const upload = multer({storage:storage}).single('img_perfil')

module.exports = upload;
```

Luego en nuestro controlador tenemos lo siguiente:

**routes/user.js** (ES5)

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const upload = require('path/to/upload');
const Usuario = require('path/to/user.model');

router.post('/uploadImage/:id', upload, (req, res)=>{ // <= pasamos el middleware que subirá la imagen
// después de que nuestro middleware se ejecuta, tendremos disponible el nombre del archivo en el objeto 'req'
    Usuario.findByIdAndUpdate( // <= una sola consulta a Mongo
        req.params.id, // <= aqui pasamos el 'id' a buscar
        {$set: {'url_img_perfil': req.file_name}}, // <= Aqui pasamos el nombre del archivo a establecer
        {new: true} // <= Esta opción indica que debe traer el resultado ya actualizado
        )
    .exec((err, result) => { // <= result contiene el Usuario actualizado
        if(err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                error: err.message
            });
        }
        if(!result) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: 'Esto es extraño, ya que se supone que el ID existe'
            });
        }
        console.log('Usuario actualizado');
        return res.status(201).json(result); // <= enviamos el resultado al front
    });
});
```

De esta forma no sobrecargamos la funcionalidad de nuestro módulo **upload** y realizamos la tarea en el último middleware. Podrás notar que uso el método [`findByIdAndUpdate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) de Mongoose. Este método realiza una sola consulta a MongoDB, a diferencia del método que estabas aplicando, que realiza dos consultas.

Espero que esto aclare tu duda y te ayude a mejorar tu código.

**EDICIÓN**

Dado que en tus comentarios expones algunas dudas relacionadas con el hecho de saber si el usuario efectivamente subió algún archivo o no, te puedo dar la siguiente sugerencia.

**Required**

Siempre que tu archivo sea un requisito para poder realizar el procedimiento de subida al servidor, creo que deberías implementar un atributo `required` en tu vista en el frontend. Si lo pensamos bien, no tiene sentido realizar una petición HTTP al servidor para enviar un archivo si el campo que contiene el archivo está vacío.

En tu elemento `input` podrías tener algo parecido a esto:

```
<input type="file" name="img_perfil" id="img_perfil" required />
```

Hemos establecido el valor del `input` como requisito para poder realizar la solicitud, de esta forma nos aseguramos que siempre que se realice una petición HTTP a nuestro endpoint, (usando nuestra app como front), el archivo efectivamente será enviado para ser procesado.

**Opcional**

En caso que la imagen a subir sea opcional, (por ejemplo cuando el usuario se da de alta (se registra) en nuestra aplicación), podemos capturar ese caso en el lado del servidor.

Muchas veces en nuestra aplicación le damos la posibilidad a un usuario de subir una imagen para el perfil en el momento en que realiza el registro. Por norma general esta característica debe ser opcional, ya que no siempre el usuario tiene una imagen disponible al momento de registrarse.

En estos casos debemos poder detectar la situación en la cual el usuario subió realmente un archivo o no lo hizo.

El middleware `multer` no realiza esto por nosotros, pero si que nos puede informar si el formulario tenía o no un campo con el archivo.

Por ejemplo, podemos detectar si el campo `req.file_name` contiene datos o es de tipo `undefined`, de esta forma podremos tomar la decisión de actualizar o no los datos del usuario.

Normalmente para este tipo de situaciones se suele tener algo llamado imagen por defecto, que se aplicaría a todos los usuarios que por alguna razón no subieron una imagen al registrarse en nuestra aplicación.

Supongamos que en la carpeta de imágenes tenemos un archivo llamado `default_image.jpg`, entonces una forma de realizar esta tarea sería la siguiente:

**routes/user.js**

```
router.post('/uploadImage/:id', upload, (req, res)=>{ // <= pasamos el middleware que subirá la imagen
// después de que nuestro middleware se ejecuta, tendremos disponible el nombre del archivo en el objeto 'req'
    const filename = req.file_name || 'default_image.jpg'; // <= Aqui verificamos si el archivo fue o no enviado en la consulta
    Usuario.findByIdAndUpdate( // <= una sola consulta a Mongo
        req.params.id, // <= aqui pasamos el 'id' a buscar
        {$set: {'url_img_perfil': filename}}, // <= Aqui pasamos el nombre del archivo a establecer
        // si el archivo no fue subido por el usuario, entonces filename contiene a 'default_image.jpg'
        {new: true} // <= Esta opción indica que debe traer el resultado ya actualizado
        )
        .exec((err, result) => { // <= result contiene el Usuario actualizado
            if(err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    error: err.message
                });
            }
            if(!result) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    error: 'Esto es extraño, ya que se supone que el ID existe'
                });
            }
            console.log('Usuario actualizado');
            return res.status(201).json(result); // <= enviamos el resultado al front
        });
});
```

Como puedes ver, el truco está en verificar el valor de `req.file_name`. Multer ejecutará el proceso de carga de la imagen si el formulario contiene un elemento `input` con el atributo `name="img_perfil"`, si dicho elemento no existe en nuestro formulario, entonces el middleware no se ejecuta.

Como `req.file_name` es creado dentro del middleware, simplemente debemos evaluar si existe dicho campo antes de actualizar el documento del usuario.

Yo realizo esa evaluación asi:

```
const filename = req.file_name || 'default_image.jpg;
```

Si `req.file_name` es de tipo `undefined` entonces la evaluación de su valor devolverá `false` y Javascript ejecutará una segunda evaluación sobre la cadena `'default_image.jpg'`, la cual devolverá `true`, y se asignará el valor de la cadena a la variable `filename`.

El operador `||` aquí se usa como [operador de corto-circuito](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Operadores_l%C3%B3gicos), si `req.file_name` contiene un valor distinto de `null` o `undefined`, entonces su evaluación devolverá `true` y el valor almacenado en la variable `filename` será el valor del campo `req.file_name`.

Espero que esto aclare las dudas nuevas que han surgido.

Comment: Maravillosa respuesta, me surge una duda , como controlas que subas o no un fichero , es decir, que en el form hayan subido una foto y no lo hayan dejado vacio, para solo insertar si hay foto

Comment: Otra duda que me has resuelto era ¿Como paso los datos del **middleware** al **routing** ? Y por lo visto es mediante `req.nombreVariable` no?

Comment: Otra duda es porque no  usas `req.params.nombreVariable` , no es necesario la propiedad `params` ? directamente se puede mediante el `req` ???

Comment: Recuerda que `req.params` es un objeto con un propósito especial, y por lo tanto no deberíamos modificarlo. Por eso uso un atributo directamente sobre el objeto `req`. En cuanto a lo de verificar si el archivo viene o no, deberías hacerlo del lado del front si lo deseas validar como `required`. Pero si el archivo es opcional puedes crear un middleware que maneje ambos casos. Recuerda que luego de ejecutar `upload`, se llena `req.file`, podrías verificar si dicho campo es `null`, si lo es, quiere decir que no había archivo en la petición y en base a eso decides.

Comment: Magnifica respuesta. Me ha ayudado mucho. Poco a poco se van aclarando las cosas

Answer (score 0):

Ya consegui hacerlo, dejo aqui como lo hice :

```
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const mime = require('mime');
//uso db
const Usuario = require('../models/user')();



//Creamos las opciones

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:path.join(__dirname,'../imagenes'),
    filename: function(req,file,cb){
        const id = req.params.id;
        let ext  = path.extname(file.originalname);
        ext = ext.length > 1 ? ext: '.'+ mime.extension(file.mimetype);
        const fileName = id+ '_imgPerfil'+ext;

        //PROBANDO...
        console.log('PROBANDO')
        Usuario.findOne({_id:id})
        .then(usuario=>{
            console.log('THEN USUARIO = '+usuario)
            if (usuario) {
                console.log('USUARIO ENCONTRADO')
                Usuario.update(
                    {_id:req.params.id},
                    {$set: {'url_img_perfil':fileName}}
                    ).then(usuario_actualizado=>{
                        cb(null,fileName);
                    })
            }
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            cb(err,null);
        })

        //..FIN PROBANDO

        console.log('filename : ',fileName);


    }
})

const upload = multer({storage:storage}).single('img_perfil')
module.exports = upload;
```

Basicamente user mi modelo `User` y en el proceso de subir la **imagen**, si todo salia bien pues antes de terminar el **middleware** hago un `update` de mi campo `url_img_perfil` y listo