# Clases en JavaScript, duda con parámetros, constructor y super

Tags: javascript

Me encuentro aprendiendo las Clases en JavaScript y un poco de herencia en lo que es la extensión de las clases. He creado una clase Padre llamada animal. La cual contiene un nombre, un tipo, una onomatopeya y por último una comida. En el constructor paso estos mismos. Tengo entendido que acá debo pasar lo mismo que declaré en la parte de arriba pero no entiendo aún muy bien por qué. (Si me lo pudieran explicar se los agradecería) Luego de eso creo un método para mi clase Animal el cual se dedica a "presentar" de alguna forma al animal.

La duda en especifico que tengo es al momento de querer Heredar todo esto a una clase Perro, la extiendo de animal y declaro una nueva propiedad que solo tendrá la clase perro que será "mejoramigo", ahora nuevamente paso 3 variables a mi constructor, el nombre, el tipo y la comida. Luego de eso creo una instancia de Perro, llamada "taby" y le asigno lo que se puede ver en el código.

```
class Animal {
  nombre;
  tipo;
  onomatopeya;
  comida;
  constructor(nombre, tipo, onomatopeya, comida) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.tipo = tipo;
    this.onomatopeya = onomatopeya;
    this.comida = comida;
  }
  saludar() {
    console.log(
      `Hola, soy ${this.nombre}, soy del tipo animal ${this.tipo}, mi onomatopeya es ${this.onomatopeya} y me gusta comer ${this.comida}`
    );
  }
}

class Perro extends Animal{
    mejoramigo = 'No tengo'
    constructor(nombre, tipo, comida){
        super(nombre,tipo,comida)
        this.mejoramigo = 'El humano'
    }
}

const taby = new Perro('Taby', 'Mamifero', 'Me gusta mucho la comida que me hace la rocío')
console.log(taby)
```

Al momento de ejecutar un node "nombre de mi archivo". Lo que devuelve es lo siguiente:

```js
class Animal {
  nombre;
  tipo;
  onomatopeya;
  comida;
  constructor(nombre, tipo, onomatopeya, comida) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.tipo = tipo;
    this.onomatopeya = onomatopeya;
    this.comida = comida;
  }
  saludar() {
    console.log(
      `Hola, soy ${this.nombre}, soy del tipo animal ${this.tipo}, mi onomatopeya es ${this.onomatopeya} y me gusta comer ${this.comida}`
    );
  }
}

class Perro extends Animal{
    mejoramigo = 'No tengo'
    constructor(nombre, tipo, comida){
        super(nombre,tipo,comida)
        this.mejoramigo = 'El humano'
    }
}

const taby = new Perro('Taby', 'Mamifero', 'Me gusta mucho la comida que me hace la rocío')
console.log(taby)
```

Pueden ejecutar el script.

Mi segunda pregunta es: ¿Por qué la frase "'Me gusta mucho la comida que me hace la rocío" no se asigna a comida y se asigna a onomatopeya?, ¿Es por el hecho del orden en el que declare las propiedades en el constructor padre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

La clase "Animal" recibe 4 argumentos en su constructor:

- Nombre
- Tipo
- Onomatopeya
- Comida

Estos argumentos son "posicionales", significa que no puedes intercambiar su posición durante la llamada.

La Clase "Perro" extiende de la Clase "Animal" y por lo tanto, podría recibir los mismos 4 argumentos que espera el constructor de "Animal", pero estás pasando sólo 3.

El valor de "onomatopeya" es el que se encuentra en la tercera posición de los argumentos (recuerda: son posicionales), y en tu constructor de la Clase "Perro", declaras y pasas sólo 3 argumentos:

- Nombre
- Tipo
- Comida

Por lo tanto, el valor que pasas como "comida" es la tercera posición del constructor "Perro", pero al llamar a `super()` de la Clase "Animal" esta posición se corresponderá con "onomatopeya".

**SOLUCIÓN**

Una posible solución es pasar un valor `null` o `undefined` o cadena vacía en la posición que corresponde al argumento de la Clase "Animal".

Por ejemplo:

```js
class Animal {
  nombre;
  tipo;
  onomatopeya;
  comida;
  constructor(nombre, tipo, onomatopeya, comida) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.tipo = tipo;
    this.onomatopeya = onomatopeya;
    this.comida = comida;
  }
  saludar() {
    console.log(
      `Hola, soy ${this.nombre}, soy del tipo animal ${this.tipo}, mi onomatopeya es ${this.onomatopeya} y me gusta comer ${this.comida}`
    );
  }
}

class Perro extends Animal{
    mejoramigo = 'No tengo'
    constructor(nombre, tipo, comida){
        super(nombre,tipo, undefined, comida); // paso undefined como 3er argumento
        this.mejoramigo = 'El humano'
    }
}

const taby = new Perro('Taby', 'Mamifero', 'Me gusta mucho la comida que me hace la rocío')
console.log(taby)
```

Como se aprecia, no importa si el constructor "Perro" recibe menos argumentos que el constructor "Animal", lo que importa es usar los argumentos en el orden correcto en la llamada a `super()`, añadiendo los que falten.

Otra forma en la que puedes extender la Clase Animal es estableciendo la onomatopeya como parte del constructor "Perro", ya que todos los objetos de tipo Perro tendrán la misma "onomatopeya", por ejemplo:

```js
class Animal {
  nombre;
  tipo;
  onomatopeya;
  comida;
  constructor(nombre, tipo, onomatopeya, comida) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.tipo = tipo;
    this.onomatopeya = onomatopeya;
    this.comida = comida;
  }
  saludar() {
    console.log(
      `Hola, soy ${this.nombre}, soy del tipo animal ${this.tipo}, mi onomatopeya es ${this.onomatopeya} y me gusta comer ${this.comida}`
    );
  }
}

class Perro extends Animal{
    mejoramigo = 'No tengo'
    constructor(nombre, tipo, comida){
        super(nombre,tipo, "Woof", comida)
        this.mejoramigo = 'El humano'
    }
}

const taby = new Perro('Taby', 'Mamifero', 'Me gusta mucho la comida que me hace la rocío')
console.log(taby)
```

En cuanto a la propiedad `mejoramigo` en tu constructor "Perro", no tiene mucho sentido hacer una declaración previa y luego machacarla en el constructor. Podrías usar argumentos opcionales, que sólo sobreescribirán la propiedad si el mismo es recibido como llamada al constructor.

Por ejemplo:

```js
class Animal {
  nombre;
  tipo;
  onomatopeya;
  comida;
  constructor(nombre, tipo, onomatopeya, comida) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.tipo = tipo;
    this.onomatopeya = onomatopeya;
    this.comida = comida;
  }
  saludar() {
    console.log(
      `Hola, soy ${this.nombre}, soy del tipo animal ${this.tipo}, mi onomatopeya es ${this.onomatopeya} y me gusta comer ${this.comida}`
    );
  }
}

class Perro extends Animal{
    mejoramigo = 'No tengo'
    constructor(nombre, tipo, comida, mejoramigo = 'No tengo'){
        super(nombre,tipo, 'Woof', comida)
        this.mejoramigo = mejoramigo
    }
}

const taby = new Perro('Taby', 'Mamifero', 'Me gusta mucho la comida que me hace la rocío')
const sultan = new Perro('Sultán', 'Mamífero', 'Huskies', 'El humano')
console.log(taby)
console.log(sultan)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Espero que esto aclare tus dudas.

Comment: amigo, las respuestas tienen que ser propias y no de otras plataformas como ChatGPT ya que se considera plagio

Comment: Me ofendes comparándome con una IA, nunca las he usado y creo que nunca las usaría. De todas formas, para aclarar ante toda la comunidad: **NO USO chatGPT**. Tengo un [post en Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5450/cheatgpt-chatgpt-nos-ha-alcanzado-en-soes) al respecto, siendo uno de los primeros en alertar a la comunidad sobre el uso de esta herramienta. Gracias por preocuparte, pero en este caso te has equivocado. Saludos

Comment: Si lo que te despista es el *espero que esto aclare tus dudas*, puedes ver mis publicaciones más antiguas, pre pandemia, por ejemplo, y verás que siempre lo he usado. A veces hasta pienso que *cheatGPT* me robó la idea. Pero en fin, cochinas coincidencias. Por ejemplo, [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/254019/nodejs-express-librer%c3%8da-multer-asignar-a-mi-modelo-usuario-url-img-el-nombre-de/254167#254167) de 2019, pre pandemia, no existía cheatGPT (al menos no al público). Curioso que *chatGPT* haga uso de un mensaje parecido.

Comment: @JulianBuxton si piensas que una pregunta esta generada por IA, debes reportarla. Que te hace pensar que esta fue generada automaticamente???

Comment: @JulianBuxton vuelvo a preguntar... necesito pruebas...

Comment: @gbianchi los unicos con herramientas que implementan heuristica para determinar si puede ser una respuesta generada por IA son los moderadores diamantado o es fue lo que se dijo aqui:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391847/moderation-strike-results-of-negotiations

Comment: @gbianchi considero que si bien esta la pregunta que le haces al usuario no tiene sentido ya que eres el unico que puede validar si o no cae en algunas de las heuristicas ... entonces solo un moderador puede decir si o no parece ser una respuesta de una IA ...

Comment: el problema es que las buenas respuestas parecen ser generadas con una IA... aunque no sea asi ...

Comment: @MauricioContreras, muchas gracias estimado. Muy claro los conceptos te lo agradezco, por tu tiempo y tu paciencia.